# Unity: Text type issue in a ScoreManager script

Tags: c#, user-interface, text, unity-game-engine

I've done `UI Canvas` and then attached `UI Text`, named it `ScoreText`.
I also have `ScoreManager` script for resetting score and writing text into it.

**Code**

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int score;
    Text text;
    void Awake () {
        text = GetComponent <Text> ();
        score = 0;
    }
    void Update () {
        text.text = "Score: " + score;
        Debug.Log (score);
    }
}
```

The code is attached to the `ScoreText`. It is working in official unity's survival shooter tutorial and worked for my project as well.

But the problem is that **`Text text`** is not recognized.
"The Type or Namespace **`Text`** could not be found."

It worked in `unity4`. My current project is in `unity5`. 
Counting works fine in `debug.log`. Now I want to set the score text.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

at the top of your code in order to import the namespace.

Side note, the tag for Unity Game Engine is `Unity3d`, not `Unity` :)